# Flutter Firebase OTP the sms code has expired all times

Tags: firebase, flutter

i can not send confirm OTP because OTP has expired everytimes. on debug it's work fine, but on release it's not work. how to solve this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i can resolve this problem now. some device can auto send OTP but i'm not implement on auto send OTP of firebase function